# REstriction on amount of text I can input to a survey

Tags: content

I am using EE v2.11.9. Much of my website has been built by external develoers so I have limited knowledge. I seem to have a reached a limit on the amount of text / words I can enter into a 'introduction' section of a 'survey' in EE. Does anyone know how to increase or remove the limit?

Answer (score 1):

First place where i'd look is in the field configuration. Since it's called "introduction" my guess it's limited to a certain number of characters.

Your site is running on a really old version of EE. Before anything else i'd advise you to have it updated asap.